# C# 2010 compile XNA class at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, prototype, xna-4.0

I'm wondering how to compile and run a XNA class from an interaction on a C# Window Form. For example, when I click button "Play" from a C# Window Form, the game which is built in XNA classes will be compiled and run. Hope my question is clear enough.

Any helps are appreciated :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: out of interest, why does the game need to be compiled at runtime?

Comment: It's a prototyping tool for game designer. They will create game characters on a canvas in the prototype. Assign all behaviors, events,etc to those characters such as movement, collision, etc. Then when they click "Play", their design will be built in XNA, compiled and run. These user interactions happen at the runtime. That's why I need to compile XNA classes at runtime :)...hope it is clear enough

Answer (score 1):

C# classes can be compiled and run on runtime, it seems you're looking for that. You can search for examples of uses of `CSharpCodeProvider` and `ICodeCompiler` to get you started.

[Here](http://www.vsj.co.uk/articles/display.asp?id=417) is one pretty clear example of how this is achieved.

Comment: thanks a lot. It requires a lot more work to get it done, but I know where I am heading.